Would I hear the 90Hz and 150Hz signals when tuned to ILS frequencies with a basic handheld radio?
If I were to make a basic handheld radio and set it to listen to any ILS, would I hear the frequencies which tell you whether you're left or right of the center line?
On similar note, how come pilots don't hear the 90/150Hz frequencies but rather the Morse code identifier for the ILS?

There is no need to hear the 90/150 Hz frequencies.  If they are not there, the indicator would either display nothing or full range deflection to one side.

In short

Would hear the 90Hz and 150Hz signals?

You would hear them, mixed and very attenuated. If you need to decode them correctly you can use a software-defined radio.

how come pilots don't hear the 90/150Hz frequencies but rather the morse code?

The localizer receiver (VHF) receives individually three pieces of information: 90 and 150 Hz tones, and everything between 300 and 3000 Hz.

This latter range includes an ident code on 1020 Hz and an optional voice transmission used by ATC as a fallback to contact a pilot when their regular communication receiver is failed. This range is fully routed to the audio speakers.

The two tones on 90 and 150 Hz are used to drive the azimuth information of the ILS indicator, they are not routed to the speakers.


The glide slope receiver (UHF) receives only the two tones to drive the vertical indicator of the ILS. This receiver is not connected to the speakers.
Details follow.

Localizer transmitted signal
The localizer signal is a complex signal which SBO and CSB components are transmitted individually and interfere in space to produce 90 and 150 Hz which proportion varies according to the angle with the centerline. If you need to understand the spectrum of these signal, see How is varying modulation depth achieved by localizer ground transmitters?
When these two interfering signals are received together they look like a DSB-AM signal modulated with two tones, 90 and 150 Hz:

Source.
Tones can be demodulated using a VHF AM receiver (alternatively a SSB receiver). However this demodulation must be tailored to the signal carried.
In DSB-AM the two sidebands are mirrored on each side of the carrier and only half of the available bandwidth can be used to carry the modulation. For a channel spacing of 8.33 kHz, only 4 kHz are available, and in fact a standard VHF AM communication receiver is optimized to receive voice and only extract audio frequencies between 300 Hz to 3000 Hz (ICAO specifications), the significant frequencies of the human voice. The extra portions are attenuated to limit noise addition.
The ILS transmitter uses the available bandwidth to carry information at discrete audio frequencies: 90 Hz, 150 Hz and, for the identification, 1020 Hz.
AM Communication receiver
Assuming it is able to receive the localizer channel frequency, a standard communication receiver can extract the ident information, but will attenuate 90 and 150 Hz.
Still you'll receive the two ILS tones, mixed, with a prominence of one depending on the position of the receiver.
Optimized reception using a SDR
If you want to extract the tones correctly you likely need a software defined radio (SDR). Standard radio receivers are still used, but they are hardware, meaning buying components and using a soldering iron. With a SDR, the appropriate digital filters are programmatically defined at 90 and 150 Hz with steep edges. Such applications are common. Here is an example for ILS, based on the open source GNU radio.
Use of audio signals by ILS receivers
The aircraft ILS receiver filters portions of the sidebands to separately detect 90 Hz, 150 Hz, and 1020 Hz.

It routes 1020 Hz of the ident to the audio speaker for the crew. If an ATC voice transmission is superimposed to the localizer signal, it occupies the range 300-3000 Hz, and in fact this whole range is routed to the speaker.

90 and 150 Hz are compared to determine the difference of depth of modulation and to show it on the ILS indicator.


Two guidance signals must be processed separately, the localizer sent on a VHF channel and the glide slope sent on a paired UHF channel. There are actually two radio receivers.

The Wikipedia article seems to suggest that you could, with the right filters:

A receiver in front of the array will receive both of these signals mixed together. Using simple electronic filters, the original carrier and two sidebands can be separated and demodulated to extract the original amplitude-modulated 90 and 150 Hz signals. These are then averaged to produce two direct current (DC) signals. Each of these signals represents not the strength of the original signal, but the strength of the modulation relative to the carrier, which varies across the beam pattern. This has the great advantage that the measurement of angle is independent of range.[4]

Bold-formatting added.
As for what pilots hear, there's no advantage to us hearing the 90/150 Hz signals, which would be basically a buzz. But there is good reason to hear the ident, so you know you're receiving the correct station (and it isn't transmitting the T-E-S-T identifier, signifying that it's undergoing maintenance & shouldn't be use to navigate with), so the receivers are set up so that's what - and all that - we hear.

The Morse code signal is at 400Hz. There is a band pass filter on the audio output that filters out the 90Hz and 150Hz and lets you hear the 400 Hz Ident.

@Gerry Just checked the FAA.gov website and they list that both 400 and 1020 Hz tones are valid for Ident signals on NDBs. I didn't see anything specifically mentioned about the frequency when used on VOR, just that it may have an Ident signal and it might use TEST when the beacon is not in operation.

@penguin359 You are correct. 400Hz is used for ident on NDBs. VORs and LOCs use 1020Hz. The ILS or VOR receiver has an internal band-pass filter for the nav signal and one for the audio. What goes thru the audio bandpass filter is sent to the audio output. On some newer receivers, the audio is digitally processed to decode the morse code. It can then send the ident information to the displays over a digital bus, typically ARINC 429.
